# need to share leaflet popup content

Tags: javascript, facebook, leaflet

I need to share the content inside a popup marker to facebook and twitter, is there an easy way to do that? I was trying with the facebook share dialog but I cant make it work, any help?.Thanks!!!

```
<a href="#" 
onclick="
window.open(
  'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
  'facebook-share-dialog', 
  'width=626,height=436'); 
return false;">
Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the expanded version of the sharer.php URL so you can define the title, description and image. These are passed using the p[title], p[url], p[summary] and p[images] parameters in the URL.

```
<a href="#" 
  onclick="
    window.open(
      'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=titlehere&p[url]=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + '&p[summary]=yoursummaryhere&p[images][0]=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fimages%2Fsrpr%2Flogo3w.png, 
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436'); 
return false;">
Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Comment: not working. Seems like facebook actually uses for the title and description of the shared content  the meta-tags in the header of the page for “title” and “description”.